# Notational way to say that something is a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

When you want to say, for example, that $a$ is an integer, you write it as $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, which is read as "$a$ is an element of the set of all integers".
But, because of the notorious nonexistence of the set of all sets, you can't say something like $S \in \mathbb{S}$, where $\mathbb{S}$ is my goofy nonce-glyph for said nonexistent set. Is there any valid *notational* way to indicate that $S$ is a set?

If I'm writing a mathematical paper, I'll just write out "$S$ is a set" in English for the sake of clarity, but for my own notes I prefer to lean on notation as much as possible for the sake of brevity and unambiguity. Notes being notes, I do take liberties, but I'd like to adhere to standards if the standards are there.

Is it possible to quantify something as a set *without* simply saying, in natural language, that it is a set?

Comment: NO; in any context, a set $S$ is a "set of something" : a set of naturals, a set of reals, a set of continuously differentiable functions, a set of formulas, a set of humans... Thus, we can Always introduce some specific symbol like e.g. $\text {WFF}$ for the collection of formulas of the language or $\text {Hum}$ for the collection of human beings.

Comment: In most "working" mathematics, everything is a set (even integers) constructed from first principles.  So saying that something "is a set" is not informative.  What we we are generally at pains to say is something about *what kind* of set $S$ is, and in most cases the notation that says the first thing *about* $S$ will also convey that it is a set.  For example, we may want to convey that $S$ is a finite set, and use notation $|S|\in \mathbb N$.

Comment: There is no "set of all sets" but it does make sense to speak of the "class of all sets". So you could say $S\in\mathscr{C}$, where $\mathscr{C}$ is that class. Classes are more general objects than sets; all sets are classes, not all classes are sets. Classes are extraordinarily "large" compared to sets. Try Googling it.

Comment: The word is *qualify*, not *quantify* something as a set. The notation $S\in \operatorname{Ob}(\mathbf{Set})$, or perhaps $S\in \mathbf{Set}$, is occasionally used in a context in which the [category of sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_sets) has been defined or is understood. It doesn't save much space, though.

Comment: Also: Just say "$S$ is a set." You're writing a paper, not a single gigantic formula. I find it irritating to see mathematical symbols in English sentences with no real justification (like saying "suppose $x\in A \wedge f(x)\notin B$" instead of "suppose $x\in A$ and $f(x)\notin B$"). It doesn't save any real space, and it is far less readable. Just because it seems "more mathy" doesn't mean it's good.

Comment: @hardmath
The context where I might use this might be existential quantification. "There exists some set _S_..." From what you're saying it sounds like it would be appropriate to just say $\exists(S, ...)$, i.e. "There exists some _S_ such that...", but that feels really sloppy. Was it a lie-to-children when my professor telling me "quantify ABSOLUTELY EVERYTHING"?

Comment: You can make the convention that by default any letter denotes a set, so you don't need to say anything.

Comment: @MPW: I'm not writing a paper, though. In my question, I explicitly say that _if I were_ writing a paper, I would probably (I say "probably" because I'm still trying to account for all my options) just write out "_S_ is a set." I'm not going to make a habit out of writing ugly frankenproofs with moon runes macaronically embedded into every sentence.

I too dislike the gratuitous mixture of mathematical notation and English text. That's why I tend to stick to symbols in my notes; symbols are often _more_ readable to me, I find. It's also why I'm asking this question.

Comment: @FoobieBletch : Yes, just taking the opportunity to rant about a pet peeve. Not saying *you* are doing this.

Comment: Can you please give an actual example where you would use this notation? It is not clear to me how you would actually need to use this in practice. Perhaps use of a conventional [Domain of discourse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_discourse) is the answer you are looking for.

Comment: @Somos
Say I wanted to define a function $f(S, T)$ where $S$ and $T$ are sets, and $f(S, T) = (S \cap T) \cup f(\{R \in S | R \notin T\}, T)$. Essentially, a way to "flatten" out a set of sets $S$ to extract all of the integers (for example) in $S$ itself or in a set nested arbitrarily deep within $S$: $f(\{\{ 2, 3\}, \{\{\{13\}\}\},\{2,3,5,7,11\}\}, \mathbb{Z})=\{2,3,5,7,11,13\}$.

Comment: @Somos (What would happen if there was a non-integer number somewhere in there? I don't know; that's why I want to research this, and why I'm looking for a notational way to say that something is a set! The English language is getting pretty unwieldy here.)

Comment: @FoobieBletch You may be interested in the Wikipedia article [Urelement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement) where certain objects are **not** sets, so there may be a need to express that an object is or is not a set.